# My image won't resize fully when viewed in Outlook

Tags: html, image

I have a 1px by 1px image in my email flyer and I have extended the height to 650px so it creates a vertical line through the middle of my table. The problem is that it works fine in browsers but when it's viewed in Outlook 10 it only stretches to about 200px, even if I increase the amount of height, it doesn't change.

I'm not using CSS for the height of the image as I know Outlook doesn't play nice with some CSS code.

HTML:

```
<th width="30" rowspan="13" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="row" ><img src="dot.png" width="1" height="650" /></th>
```

Comment: Outlook ok which version?

Comment: try height="650" on th

Comment: Maybe you should add an element with a left border instead of an image. Outlook will show inline styles, so by adding `style="border-left: 1px solid blue"`, you can give the table or cell a 1px border.

Comment: @GolezTrol I didn't want to use that method as I want the line to be dead center. using `border-left` would place the line just off center

Comment: @AlexGarulli ...and nope, adding height to the th didn't do anything

Comment: mmm weird try add style="height:650px" on img tag

Comment: Nope, that time my line disappeared :/

Comment: maybe thi help http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3103/maximum-height-for-images-in-email-outlook/